# How to use void pointer(void*)

Tags: c++

void actually is not a specific type. So how can the system determine the end of the memory block thus cipher the value of the data block? surely you can change the type from void to specific type if you know the data in the memory, but when you don't? What's the purpose for the language designer to make this concept?

Comment: Go read a C or C++ book...

Comment: with void*  you cannot predict the end of data, one has to tyoecast the void* to specific type to get the data boundary.

Comment: 1. Add some more useful description of what your problem is and what you're trying to do. 2. Show some code to make your question clearer.

Comment: If you are down to bytes usually void* goes with a accompanying length parameter as in 
`void buffer(void*, int len);` 
or similar.

Comment: His question is completely clear. This is just a classic case of arbitrarily deciding 'well that's just too basic for that standards here at SO', hence the snobby comments with upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

This was used mainly in C to pass data to callback functions or to build generic containers. It is used, whenever you want to abstract from the concrete data type. The type "void *" is just able to pass pointers on, sometimes that's all you need.

But you are right, if you want to actually access the data, you have to cast the pointer type back to a concrete data type at some point. So *some* code has to actually remember the type (and it has to get it right, otherwise you just read rubbish!). But not *all* the code has to know the type. Some functions can just refer to it as "void *" and therefore be more abstract: The same implementation of e.g. a linked list can then be used to contain strings or matrices or whatever you want, without having to reprogram the list code for every type.

In C++ you can avoid the potentially unsafe casting by using inheritance (interfaces) in the case of callback data or templates in the case of containers.

Btw. in C/C++ in many cases you cannot actually know the "end of the data block", that's not special to the "void *" pointers. That is why there are so many dangerous buffer overflows.

Answer (score 1):

> So how can the system determine the end of the memory block thus cipher the value of the data block?

It can't. It's up to you to know what type is there, and cast the pointer appropriately to access it.

> but when you don't?

Then you can't use `void*`.

> What's the purpose for the language designer to make this concept?

It's a hangover from C, where it is the only way to pass a generic type around. For example, the `qsort` library function uses it to pass pointers to arbitrary types through to the user-provided comparison function; it's up to the user to know what the real type is, and cast the pointers back to perform the comparison.

In C++, it serves little purpose - there are more reliable ways (including templates and inheritance-based polymorphism) to support generic types. For example, the equivalent `std::sort` is a template, and preserves the correct type throughout.

Answer (score 0):

As for my experience, i'll say it's like a joker, it allow you to pass a pointer to a function without knowing the type of the pointer. For example, in C, a "generic" implementation of linked list would have a void * pointer to the data, allowing multiple data type to be added

Answer (score 0):

It's used as a placeholder. Eventually the pointer will be passed to a function that does know what the actual type will be.

An example is a generic sorting function. It takes an array, which can contain any type (so this is `void*`), and a comparison function. The comparison function should be appropriate to the type of the array, so it will cast the `void*` pointer to the correct `type*` before dereferencing the values.

This is mostly a holdover from C. In C++, it's common to use templates for this.